Reducing a matrix to a single one
Given a 3 by 3 binary matrix an operation adds one row to another one using bitwise xor. You can't xor a row with itself.
What is the maximum number of bits you can have in a 3 by 3 matrix so you can get down to a matrix with a single  bit just using these operations?

The maximum is

 3

This is because

 each row xor operation is invertible -- in fact doing it again undoes it. So, working in reverse, starting from a matrix with a single 1, how many 1's can we make? The answer is 3, because we can fill the column that has the 1, but no other column.


Very fast!  Impressive.

Very appropriate username for this puzzle. LOL...
